# Improving Performance in OpenMP program

Tags: c, linux, openmp

Suppose an array `arr` of SIZE=128Mb with values from 0 to 128Mb-1. Now suppose the following code:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(NUM_THREADS)
{
  int me = omp_get_thread_num();
  odds_local[me] = 0;
  int count = 0;

#pragma omp for 
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
      if (arr[i]%2 != 0)
    count++;

  odds_local[me] = count;
}
```

and finally a loop that iterates over the values of `odds_local[me]` to get the final result. For this, if I time it and report user time in Linux I get 0.97s for both 1 thread and 2 threads. That is to say, no speedup whatsoever.

Is there anything I should be improving in this program to better the speedup?

Comment: That's not a lot of work to be worth parallelizing. What's the bigger problem that you're trying to solve. If you find yourself trying to parallelize trivial things like this, there might be a better way if you take into account the big picture.

Comment: This is for a class I'm teaching. It has to be a toy example of solving false sharing (an example I have somewhere else). This should solve FS since all vars are local to the threads except for the last assignment. Wondering if I can do anything to show that OpenMP works :)

Comment: Ah. That example isn't gonna have false sharing because OpenMP will block the iterations rather than interleave them. Demoing false-sharing is tricky because you need to fight compiler's optimizations like mad.

Comment: No, no, sorry... I have a false sharing example using OpenMP. That works fine. What I don't have is decent speedup with the code I posted :)

Comment: Oops, misread your comment. Try putting something much more expensive in the loop. Make a few calls to `sin()`, `log()`, or some ugly integer divisions. That'll "slow" it down enough to show a speedup.

Comment: `++count` is faster than `count++`, likewise for `i++`/`++i`, though by how much I don't know.

Comment: @MattPhillips: Thanks, but that's too much microoptimization for me (besides, it would work in the serial program as well). I just want OpenMP to do what it is supposed to do :)

Comment: Hmm, this should work. Do you have OpenMP enabled?

Comment: @MattPhillips: With `count` being `int` I seriously doubt that this is true for any kind of optimizing compiler, exspecially since the result of the operation isn't used.

Comment: From your question I assume that you take your time measurements are based on unixs user time. IIRC that will give you the sum of the execution times over all threads. So your timing might be a bit flawed, since it won't matter if you do the whole work in one thread or 1/n of the work in n threads.

Comment: @Grizzly: I do it with `perf`, which still does aggregation, but I also know the CPU utilization (which still hides info, but at still I know part of the truth). I don't know of any tool in Linux that would allow me to measure time per thread... maybe something like VTune, but that software is terrible. I could also RDTSC on the threads, getting times *per CPU*, but that's too much work for what I'm doing right now. Do you know of a tool that does what you say in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I ran your exact code and with 1 thread I get 390ms, with 2 I get 190ms. Your problem is not in the code. It has to be something basic. These are the things I can think of:

- not linking with OpenMP (with `g++ filename -fopenmp`);
- running on a single core machine;
- running on a dual core, with something else occupying the other core;
- timing something more than this loop, which is dominating the calculation.